# Blender to create a "skin" for a model?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a 3D version of a skin for a phone, tablet, computer, etc., so I can render realistic looking images of them in Keyshot.  So I'm looking for a way to bring in a model of something like an iPhone (that either I create or purchase from someone), create a new part that would wrap around the area I need a skin to apply around, and keep a UV map of that skin so textures will wrap the way they would in real life.

Ideally I'd like to be able to create the skin part directly from the model of the device.

Is Blender a good tool to use for something like this, or should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: well, it should be possible: from the device object mesh you can obtain a "skin" starting from a duplicate, and then scaling it up a bit, leaving holes where screen, buttons, mic and headphone jack (if is not an iphone 7 of course :D) are... but what is the ultimate goal? 3d print?

Comment: The ultimate goal for this is to use the part in rendering realistic images for our website.  If there was a way to create the skin from a model, and then flatten it so it could be cut from a sticker material, that'd be even better as it'd give me a closer starting point for the actual cutpath.  Flattening it isn't as big of a deal though, since I've got to create the path and test it anyway.

Comment: mmm no, I misunderstood what you meant, can you show or link an example image of the desired result?

Comment: The end result will look similar to this: [link](http://imgur.com/a/oIg4q).  Where the wood  material would be the "skin" on top of the iPhone model.

Ideally, I'd be able to wrap a flat shape around it so the grain of the wood would look correct on the corners, similar to the outline of the path in this image: [link](http://www.bestskinsever.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/610x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/i/P/iPhone-7-Plus-total-body-skin.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I dont' know if this at least partly answers, but this is a "skin" I built around a "phone" mesh... obviously very simple, and rough, that fits it nicely, because I built it as said above, duplicating the "phone" mesh, cutting "holes" where necessary, and then scaling it up a bit in every direction...

[image]

then, the skin cover could be decorated as needed, rendered etc.